# LuaJ How to avoid overriding existing entries in Globals table

Tags: lua, luaj

I am loading different Lua scripts using LuaJ into the globals environnment as follows in Java:

```
globals = JmePlatform.standardGlobals();
LuaValue chunk = globals.load(new FileInputStream(luaScriptA), scriptName, "t", globals);
chunk.call();
```

My problem is that if for example the scriptName happens to be **require, print, error, math** or any other name that already exists in globals after calling

```
globals = JmePlatform.standardGlobals();
```

, the script will in fact replace/override the actual functionality such as print.

Is there any simple way to prevent this from happening?

Unfortunately a test such as:

```
if (globals.get(scriptName) != Globals.NIL) {
    //then dont allow script load
}
```

will not work for me as there are cases that it should actually override an existing script, when the script is updated.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend never storing libraries in the global scope, for exactly this reason. See http://www.luafaq.org/#T1.37.2 for a way of loading modules and libraries using `required`. I'm not sure if this works on LuaJ, but if it implements `require` correctly, you can make a loader function and put it in `package.loaders`.

Basically, you define your libraries like this:

```
-- foo.lua
local M = {}

function M.bar()
    print("bar!")
end

return M
```

And import them like this:

```
-- main.lua
local Foo = require "foo"
Foo.bar() -- prints "bar!"
```

See the [documentation of require](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-require) for implementing the loading function.