# How to make global variables "immutable" in Lua/LuaJ?

Tags: lua, luaj, readonly-variable

**Description**

I'm doing a LuaJ program, and here's a lib script like this:

```lua
function foo()
    print("foo");
end
```

I want the `foo` function can be invoked in other scripts **directly** (no `require`), but performs immutable in different scripts. ( Even a script overrides it, it performs as the original way in other scripts. )

For example, here's the script 1:

```lua
foo = function()
    print("bar");
end
```

and here is the script 2:

```lua
foo();
```

**What's done**

I have saw these two questions. They do work but not the solution to this problem.

[LuaJ How to avoid overriding existing entries in Globals table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23137894/luaj-how-to-avoid-overriding-existing-entries-in-globals-table)

[Preventing Function Overriding in Lua Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23802559/preventing-function-overriding-in-lua-table/23816383)

[Making global environment access-only (Lua)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145984/making-global-environment-access-only-lua)

---

I tried loading lib every time exec a script, or set `local _ENV`, but because there may be further callbacks from Java to Lua, it doesn't work correctly.

I now handle it by create a `Globals` and load lib script every time load a script in Java like this:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        loadAndCallViaDifferentEnv(libPath, script1);
        loadAndCallViaDifferentEnv(libPath, script2);
    }

    static void loadAndCallViaDifferentEnv(String libPath, String scriptPath) {
        Globals globals = JsePlatform.standardGlobals();
        globals.loadfile(libPath).call();
        globals.loadfile(scriptPath).call();
    }
```

It works well, but costs much. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you want to protect three functions from overwriting: `foo1`, `foo2` and `print`

```
-- define foo1 and foo2 inside protected table instead of as usual globals
local protected = {}

function protected.foo1()  
   print("foo1");
end

function protected.foo2()
   print("foo2");
end

-- if a function to be protected already exists, remove it from globals:
protected.print = print
print = nil

-- Now set the metatable on globals
setmetatable(_G, {
   __index = protected,
   __newindex =
      function(t, k, v)
         if not protected[k] then
            rawset(t, k, v)
         end
      end
})
```

Now you can invoke `foo1`, `foo2` and `print` from other modules without `require`, but you can not overwrite them:

```
-- the script 1:
foo1 = function()
   print("bar");
end
foo1();   -- original protected.foo1() is invoked
```

```
-- the script 2:
foo1();   -- original protected.foo1() is invoked
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it slightly differently by "hiding" a special field. This makes the table immutabily not require a new metatable for each one

```
-- Imm{hi='immutable'}: make a table immutable.
-- A performant immutable table implementation. We actually hide the table
-- inside rawget(f, '#frozen'), but nobody needs to know that!

local Imm = setmetatable({
  __name='Imm', __fmt=mty.tblFmt,
  __newindex=function() error('invalid operation on Imm', 2) end,
  __index=function(v, k) return rawget(v, '#frozen')[k] end,
  __pairs=function(v)    return pairs(rawget(v, '#frozen')) end,
  __ipairs=function(v)   return ipairs(rawget(v, '#frozen')) end,
  __len=function(v)      return #rawget(v, '#frozen') end,
}, {__name='ImmTy', __call=function(ty_, t)
  return setmetatable({['#frozen']=t}, ty_) end
})
```

Soon to be available in https://github.com/civboot/civlua/blob/main/ds/ds.lua